# List start at the bottom of the container and append upwards

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to make a chat box, where the messages start at the bottom. Right now, the chat box will keep the first message at the bottom of the sheet, but I would like the new messages to go to the bottom of the container.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hm4tF.png)

Here is the css for the container.

```
#messageList {
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    height: 300px;
    max-height: 300px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content:flex-end;
}
```

Here's where the message is added to the view.

```
        var li = document.createElement("li");
        li.textContent = encodedMsg;
        var list = document.getElementById("messageList");
        list.insertBefore(li, list.firstChild);
```

Any help much appreciated and have a good day.

Answer (score 1):

Use `prepend` instead. Here is a simple example I wrote:

```
 var li = document.createElement("li");
        li.textContent = 'a';
        var list = document.getElementById("messageList");
        list.append(li)

var li2 = document.createElement("li");
        li2.textContent = 'b';
        list.prepend(li2)
```

"b" will come before "a"

Answer (score 0):

Use `:first` selector to select first element then use `insertBefore()`.

```js
$('input[type="text"]').keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.which == '13') {
        if($('ul li').length == 0) {
          $('ul').html(`<li>${this.value}</li>`);
        } else {
          $(`<li>${this.value}</li>`).insertBefore('li:first');
        }
        
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul></ul>
<input type="text">
```